# Fill lines with color in table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fill every 2 lines in a table but I want the colored lines to stop at the last column. Here is my code, could you please tell me what is wrong?

```
Sub FormatChargeCompleted()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, x As Long, y As Long

Workbooks("sample.xls").Worksheets("sample").Activate

LR = Worksheets("sample").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Worksheets("sample").Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 1 To LR Step 2
    For Columns.Value = 1 To LC
        Rows(x).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Next Columns.Value
Next x

End Sub
```

Thank!

Comment: Why don't you use `Conditional Formatting` instead of coding? Btw, using `Columns.Value` in your `For Loop` is not correct. You should use a variable (e.g. `y` in your example) to execute the loop properly. Also, you are using `Rows(x)` which will always color the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comments, I tried re-writing your code.

```
Sub FormatChargeCompleted()
    Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, x As Long, fillrng As Range
    With Worksheets("sample")
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For x = 1 To LR Step 4
            If fillrng Is Nothing Then
                Set fillrng = .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 1, LC - 1))
            Else
                Set fillrng = Union(fillrng, .Range(.Cells(x, 1), _
                    .Cells(x + 1, LC - 1)))
            End If
        Next
        If Not fillrng Is Nothing Then fillrng.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Here are some of the errors I've spotted.

1. Your `LC` will not reflect the last column correctly. `Columns.Count` should be at the `ColumnIndex` not on `RowIndex`.
2. Your step should be 4 and not 2 if what you're trying to achieve is every 2 lines filling as shown above.

If this is not the result you need, then might as well post a sample illustration or you can play around with the code and adjust it to suit. HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for. I am trying what your showing me in my code right now and with a little playing around, should be able to make it look as needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, here is the code I was looking for, which I found while looking at L42's answer:

```
Sub FormatChargeCompleted()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, x As Long, y As Long, fillrng As Range

Workbooks("sample.xlsx").Worksheets("sample").Activate

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 1 To LR
    If WorksheetFunction.IsOdd(x) Then
        For y = 1 To LC
            Cells(x, y).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        Next y
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding, format the range as a table. There are several built in color schemes, many of which contain alternating row colors. And when you add/insert/delete rows, the alternating pattern will apply automatically.

As a bonus, the header row contains drop-downs for filtering and sorting.

All that without a single line of code.

[image]

Comment: I believe OP wants every 2 lines fill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first reason I rather do it in vba is because this is just a small part of a macro that manipulates 2 csv files into a weekly report. The other reason is because I just started using vba and I want to use it as much as possible right now so that when I'll need it in the future, I'll be able to use it in a time effective manner ;)